# Getting data from MySQL table with 25+ columns using django model

Tags: python, mysql, django, machine-learning, django-rest-framework

I have a MySQL db (companies_data) with 4 tables (all_users, freq_user, special_users, products). `all_users` table has 27 columns and thousands of rows, I use that data to feed my machine learning algorithms.

I'm using python, django rest_framework for backend.

Now I wanted to get those data using django model and convert it into pandas dataframe so that I can predict and add the predictions to the other tables. Is there a easy way to get all the data using django model?

Now I'm using raw SQL query with all the column names to get the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a django-model for these tables?
Generally speaking, you can have a django model for each of the tables, then build the queryset for what fields you want (you can also filter) and that's it.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from myapp.models import BlogPost


# limit which fields
queryset = User.objects.filter(...).annotate(...).values_list('f1','f2',...)
df = pd.DataFrame(list(queryset), columns=['f1','f2',...])
```

Comment: No I don't but I wanted to know how can l create django model for 27 columns?, Do I have to create 27 fields for that table? Or is there any easy way to accomplish that?

Comment: yes, if you want to do it through django models, but you can load it without going through django models

Comment: Ok, can you give me a sample django model
Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial02/#creating-models